# Snapshot shows timezone name instead of GMT code in CI server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I'm using a snapshot test in my project and came across a weird problem when running this specific test on a CI server: it displays the timezone name instead of the GMT code, causing the test failure.

I have tried using "moment-timezone" and Date.UTC() to normalize the dates, the result shown was the correct date with the same issue as above.

I've also tried to stub the *global.Date* object, but the components complained about prop incompatibility.

```
 it('should render with props', () => {
    const order = {
      merchant: { logo: 'abc', name: 'Pizza Hut' },
      bag: {
        items: [{ name: 'Corn & Bacon' }],
        total: {
          valueWithDiscount: 99.99,
        },
      },
      delivery: {
        deliversAt: new Date('2019-05-21 13:00'),
      },
      payment: {
        mode: 'online',
      },
      lastStatus: API_STATUSES.cancelled,
      createdAt: new Date('2019-05-21 12:00'),
      details: {},
    };
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Order, {
      ...commons,
      propsData: { order },
    });
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

See that the expected date is the same as the received one, but syntactic differences:

```
        <div class="order__details">
    -     <orderdetails-stub paymentmode="online" deliverytime="Fri Jun 21 2019 10:00:00 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)" value="99.99" laststatus="cancelled"></orderdetails-stub>
    +     <orderdetails-stub paymentmode="online" deliverytime="Fri Jun 21 2019 10:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)" value="99.99" laststatus="cancelled"></orderdetails-stub>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Date strings as props like this is hazardous and likely to lead to the sort of problem you're encountering.

Best practice for tests in my experience is to use `Date.getTime()` so values are numbers of milliseconds without any locale information.

Alternatively, you can use `moment-timezone` as described in [this article](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/jest-snapshot-testing-with-dates-and-times-f3badb8f1d87):

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  moment.tz.setDefault('EST');
  let props = {
    currentDay: moment("2017-09-15 09:30:00").format("MMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a")
  };

  const tree = renderer.create(<App {...props} />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the Date string could be affecting the test like so, but I couldn't figure out what exactly was going wrong. I'll be using that `Date.getTime()` trick, it should be simple to refactor